# Why is jQuery.fx.off returning 'undefined'?

Tags: jquery

In jquery **jQuery.fx.off** will return `bool`. But when I am executing the following line I am getting `undefined`.

```
alert(jQuery.fx.off);
```

Please tell me why is it so.

Comment: Very sure. Please see the link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly set it. The value is set with `$.fx.off = !$.fx.off`, but `undefined` is considered falsey, meaning that `!undefined` will return `true`.

Comment: if you see in source - all checking like `jQuery.fx.off ? ... : ...` so by default it simply not defined, because _false_ and _undefined_ have same behavior in this case

Comment: Now i came to understand, thanks for all your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent versions, at least, jQuery doesn't assign an initial value to `jQuery.fx.off`, leaving it `undefined` by default.

[jQuery just tests whether it has a value and if that value is *truthy*](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.1/src/effects.js#L430):

```
jQuery.speed = function( speed, easing, fn ) {
    // ...

    opt.duration = jQuery.fx.off ? 0 : // ...
        //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To get a boolean based on its *truthiness*, you can use the `Boolean()` function (without `new`) or [double `!!`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript):

```
alert(jQuery.fx.off); // undefined

var fxOff = Boolean(jQuery.fx.off);
alert(fxOff);         // false
```